# ionic2 - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic2

I have 3 pages(adopt, adopt-design, adopt-invite) which I am using `navCtrl.push()` to go forward and `<button ion-fab mini navPop>` to pop back to previous page. It works well on browser. but when I want to build for `iOS`, I get this error:

> [10:22:20]  Error: Error at
>   /Users/xuanxi/Desktop/bitbuckets/meta/metatest/.tmp/pages/adopt-design/adopt-design.ngfactory.ts:402:29
>
> [10:22:20]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   [10:22:20]  Error at
>   /Users/xuanxi/Desktop/bitbuckets/meta/metatest/.tmp/pages/adopt-invite/adopt-invite.ngfactory.ts:253:29
>
> [10:22:20]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.
>   [10:22:20]  ngc failed

I am using `sidemenu` template, so I suspect it has something to do with `@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;` and `this.nav.setRoot(page.component);` at the `app.component.ts` but I am not sure how to resolve this. Below are my code for `adopt` and `adopt-design.ts`:

**adopt.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AdoptDesign } from '../adopt-design/adopt-design';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-adopt',
  templateUrl: 'adopt.html'
})
export class Adopt {
  selectedItem: any;
  icons: string[];
  items: Array<{title: string, note: string, icon: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
    this.icons = ['flask', 'wifi', 'beer', 'football', 'basketball', 'paper-plane',
    'american-football', 'boat', 'bluetooth', 'build'];

    this.items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      this.items.push({
        title: 'Model ' + i,
        note: 'input : ' + i,
        icon: this.icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.icons.length)]
      });
    }
  }

  itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.navCtrl.push(AdoptDesign, {
    });
  }
}
```

**adopt-design.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AdoptInvite } from '../adopt-invite/adopt-invite';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-adopt-design',
  templateUrl: 'adopt-design.html'
})
export class AdoptDesign {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  gotoInvite(event) {
    this.navCtrl.push(AdoptInvite, {
    });
  }
}
```

which `adopt-design.ts` have similar structure.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried not passing empty object as second parameter to `this.navCtrl.push(AdoptInvite, { });`?

Comment: I tried `this.navCtrl.push(AdoptInvite);`, still have same build error.

Answer (score 1):

```
gotoInvite(event?: Event) {
  this.navCtrl.push(AdoptInvite, {});
}
```

Just do it like these. Interrogation mark is used when the argument is auxilary. It worked with me.